# JSON output of one PHP Script as input to another script in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have A.php script which converts the CSV file in JSON. Now that output is saved in another JSON file by manually copy pasting. 
B.php script uses that JSON file and shows the table like data in a browser. 
I want to skip the first step where I have to copy paste the JSON output from A.php and store it in the file so B.php can use it.

How can I input the A.php files output as input to B.php?
How do I do that?

PS- I am very new to PHP scripting.

Comment: What will make it even easier is to turn everything that happens in A.php into a function that returns json. In B.php you simply call the function.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of (or as well as) saving the JSON to a file, you can have your A.php script `return` the JSON. Then you can get it in file B.php by using [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-158).

So in file A.php:

```
// $json = however you are getting it from the CSV
// optionally output to file (if you still want to do this for some other reason)
return $json;
```

(Be sure the `return` is the last thing in your script, because nothing after it will execute.)

And in file B.php:

```
// instead of $json = [PASTE FILE CONTENTS HERE], do this:
$json = include 'A.php';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. But I have another problem now. My B.php use to show output in html format which now it dont. It shows all html tag instead of showing it as table.

Comment: That's strange. That doesn't sound like something that should have been caused by this change. Was the different way of getting the JSON the only change you made to B.php?

Comment: Yes, as soon as i use include, output get changed to HTML tag. I am 100% sure that i am doing something wrong here.
See below if i comment include and uncomment the last line it shows output in HTML

<html>
    <head>
        <title> Report</title>
        <style>
        table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
        td { text-align: center;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
include 'A.php';
$reportinfo = json_decode($abc);
#$reportinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("sb.json"));

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use an external json file, you could do that with file handler php functions.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('data.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $file_A_results);
fclose($fp);
```

And after that, you would have to call B.php manually... so consider Don't Panic's answer aswell!